# iOS Custom View Size Inside UINavigationController When Toolbar Shown

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, toolbar

I have a pretty straightforward setup: A `UINavigationController` with `setToolbarHidden NO`. So the container for the custom view inside the stuff owned by the `UINavigationController` should be the distance from the bottom of the navigation bar to the top of the toolbar.
[image: expected distance]

However, what I get is (as you might be able to glean from the screen shot by looking through the translucent toolbar) the distance from the bottom of the nav bar to the bottom of the screen.

I've set the `autoresizingMask` to `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth` in my `viewDidAppear`, but it never gets the "right" answer that takes the toolbar height into account. I can calculate the toolbar height and subtract it from the view height, resetting the height of the custom view, but the real problem re-emerges when the device is rotated. This seems like an autoresize kind of problem and I'm baffled why the toolbar isn't taken into account.

Any tips how to have the custom view resize, taking the space the toolbar occupies into account?

A couple of notes:

1. I am creating all of this programmatically, not using IB
2. I've examined it in Symbiote, which is very reliable (at least for me) and it verifies what I can see and measure via `NSLog` output

I see apps doing this all the time, so I feel like I must be missing something.

Code:

```
// Code translated from RubyMotion

view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.tableView.accessibilityLabel = @"events table";
self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.tableView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

self.tableView.dataSource = self;
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar; // assume I created a searchbar

[self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the code used to create this views? Maybe there's a bug there...

Comment: could you log the frame of your view and the frame of the tableview? just to know what they are exactly

Comment: Here it is (oddly, both are exactly the same size, which is the device size. These loggings are from viewDidAppear:

2013-02-07 12:23:02.021 View frame is #<CGRect origin=#<CGPoint x=0.0 y=0.0> size=#<CGSize width=320.0 height=416.0>>
2013-02-07 12:23:02.022 Table frame is #<CGRect origin=#<CGPoint x=0.0 y=0.0> size=#<CGSize width=320.0 height=416.0>>

Answer (score 0):

When you make the toolbar translucent, the content view is automatically sized to consume the space all the way down to the bottom of the bar, corresponding to the fact that you expect to see something through it.  When you make the toolbar opaque, the content view will be sized to fit in the space denoted by the arrow in your drawing.

So somewhere in your `viewDidLoad`, you can set:

```
self.navigationController.toolbar.translucent = NO;
```

Although really, this should be the default value, so you must be setting it to `YES` somewhere, if not in this view controller then perhaps in a parent?